# dplyr count unique and repeat id's by months

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that looks like the following:

```
ID    DATE
12     10-20-20
12     10-22-20
10     10-15-20
9      10-10-20
11     11-01-20
7      11-02-20
```

I would like to group by month and then create a column for unique id count and repeat id count like below:

```
MONTH      Unique_Count    Repeat_Count
 10-1-20         2                2            
 11-1-20         2                0
```

I am able to get the date down to the first of the month and group by ID but I am not sure how to count unique instances within the months.

```
df %>%
mutate(month = floor_date(as.Date(DATE), "month")) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(count = n())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(month = strftime(floor_date(as.Date(DATE, "%m-%d-%y"), "month"), 
                          "%m-%d-%y")) %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(unique_count = length(which(table(ID) == 1)),
            repeat_count = sum(table(ID)[(which(table(ID) > 1))]))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   month    unique_count repeat_count
#>   <chr>           <int>        <int>
#> 1 10-01-20            2            2
#> 2 11-01-20            2            0
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my answer below.

Comment: This is close but for each month I need the number of id's that only appear once as well as the number of id's that appear more than once

Comment: @user3249770 Sorry, I misread the expected output. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at it:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dates <- as.Date(c("2020-10-15", "2020-10-15", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-16"))
ids <- c(12, 12, 13, 13, 14)

df <- data.frame(dates, ids)

duplicates <- df %>%
  group_by(dates_floored = floor_date(dates, unit = "month"), ids) %>%
  mutate(duplicate_count = n()) %>%
  filter(duplicate_count > 1) %>%
  distinct(ids, .keep_all = TRUE)

uniques <- df %>%
  group_by(dates_floored = floor_date(dates, unit = "month"), ids) %>%
  mutate(unique_count = n()) %>%
  filter(unique_count < 2) %>%
  distinct(ids, .keep_all = TRUE)

df_cleaned <- full_join(uniques, duplicates, by = c("ids", "dates", "dates_floored")) %>%
  group_by(dates_floored) %>%
  summarize(count_duplicates = sum(duplicate_count, na.rm = TRUE), 
            count_unique = sum(unique_count, na.rm = TRUE))
df_cleaned
```

Comment: Edited to match your desired output